# string read from file won't display in loop

Tags: c++, file, loops, struct, fstream

The purpose of the following code is to take user input of 6 movie titles and realease dates, write that data to a file using fstream, then read the data into 2 string characters (line1 and line2) in a loop, such that the first loop will assign line1 and line2 the first movie title and year, and the second loop will assign line1 and 2 the 2nd movie title and year, and so on, until eof.

```
// array of structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_MOVIES 6

struct movies_iit
{
    string title;
    int year;
}

films[NUM_MOVIES];
// global variables
char title[20], y, n;
int year;
string search;
// function 1
void sort_on_title(movies_iit films[], int n)
{
    // Local struct variable used to swap records
    movies_iit temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            /* If s[i].title is later in alphabet than
s[i+1].title, swap the two records */
            if (films[i].title > films[i + 1].title)
            {
                temp = films[i];
                films[i] = films[i + 1];
                films[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
//end function 1
//function query1 prototype
void query1(movies_iit movie);
// function query2 prototype
void query2(movies_iit movie);
// function 2 prototype
void printmovie(movies_iit movie);

int main()
{
    // login
    // username: user
    // password: word
    string mystr, pass, name, line1, line2;
    int n;
    char response;

    // output object

    ofstream fout("data.dat");

    // input object

    ifstream fin("data.dat");
    assert(fin.is_open());
    cout << "enter your username " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "enter your password " << endl;
    cin >> pass;

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    if (name == "user" && pass == "word")
        cout << "Welcome, user." << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "###" << "unrecognized username/password combination" << "\t" << "please try     again" << "###" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits < std::streamsize > ::max(), '\n');

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    for (n = 0; n < NUM_MOVIES; n++)
    {
        cout << "Enter title: ";
        getline(cin, films[n].title);
        cout << "Enter year: ";
        getline(cin, mystr);
        stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MOVIES; ++i)
    {
        fout << films[i].title << "\n";
        fout << films[i].year << "\n";
    }
    // sort records, function 1 call
    sort_on_title(films, NUM_MOVIES);
    cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
    for (n = 0; n < NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        printmovie(films[n]); // function 2 call

    cout << "Perform an alphabetical search? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> response;

    if (response == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Please enter title" << endl;
        cin >> title;
        if (fin)
        {
            getline(fin, line1); // read first 2 recs
            getline(fin, line2);

            while (fin) // keep reading till the eof
            {
                if (line1 == "title")
                {
                    cout << " >> " << line1 << endl;
                    cout << line2 << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << line1 << endl;
                    cout << line2 << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        fin.close(); //close input file

        response == n;

    }
    else if (response == 'n')
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    else
        cout << "invalid entry" << endl;

    cout << "\n" << endl;
}

// function 2 definition
void printmovie(movies_iit movie)
{
    cout << movie.title;
    cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
// function query1 defintion
void query1(movies_iit movie)
{
    if (movie.title == "title")
    {
        cout << " >> " << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
    }
}
// function query2 definition
void query2(movies_iit movie)
{
    if (movie.year >= year)
    {
        cout << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
    }
}
```

In the loop where I read values from the file into my strings, in my output it does not display the data stored in the strings.  Why is that, and how can I fix the issue?

I realized that the code I originally posted didn't work; here is a functional one.

Comment: oh my god, please fix the indentation!

Comment: If you meant the ### comments, they're fixed.

Comment: Why are you writing in C++, when you are not even using sort function? Is it required to write it yourself?

Comment: Yes, and it must be in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the 'fout' filestream before you try to read from it using 'fin'.

fout.close();  // <== Close the output file to flush the buffered I/O

The data you are writing to the file is likely buffered (not written to the file immediately). Your data.dat file is empty when you try to read it during your search.

Comment: That solved that problem, but now instead of nothing I seem to be getting an infinite loop of sorts.  Any ideas on how to get it to display just what I want?

Comment: Your getline calls need to be inside of your while loop in your search.  Also you probably need while (! fin.eof())  in your while loop expression.  'fin' will not be null and will thus always evaluate to true in while(fin) <== always true.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close the file in which data is being stored.
2. You are matching for string "title" and not input which user has provided.
3. getline() should be inside while loop ( as you want to match all the lines and not just 1st 2 records)

   ```
     int main (){
     //login
     //username: user
     //password: word
     string mystr, pass, name, line1, line2;
     int n;
     char response;

     //output object
     ofstream fout ("data.dat");

     //input object

     cout << "enter your username "<<endl;
     cin >> name;
     cout << "enter your password "<<endl;
     cin >> pass;

     cout << "\n" << endl;

     if (name == "user" && pass == "word")
       cout << "Welcome, user." << endl;
     else
     {cout << "###" <<  "unrecognized username/password combination" << "\t" << "please try     again" << "###" << endl;
       //system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
     }

     cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

     cout << "\n" << endl;

     for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
     {
       cout << "Enter title: ";
       getline (cin,films[n].title);
       cout << "Enter year: ";
       getline (cin,mystr);
       stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
     }
     cout << "\n" << endl;
     //###################################################################################################################
     //write to file
     //###################################################################################################################
     for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MOVIES; ++i)
     {
       fout << films[i].title << "\n";
       fout << films[i].year << "\n";
     }
     fout.close();

     //sort records, function 1 call
     sort_on_title(films, NUM_MOVIES);
     cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
     for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++) 
       printmovie (films[n]);  //function 2 call

     ifstream fin("data.dat");
     assert(fin.is_open()); 


     //###################################################################################################################
     //query 1
     //###################################################################################################################
     cout << "Perform an alphabetical search? (y/n)" << endl;
     cin >> response;

     if (response == 'y')
     {cout << "Please enter title" << endl;
       cin >> title;
       if (fin.good())
       {
         while(!fin.eof())  //keep reading till the eof
         {
           getline(fin,line1); // read first 2 recs
           if(!fin.eof())
             getline(fin,line2);

           if (line1 == title)
           {
             cout << " >> " << line1 << endl;
             cout << line2 << endl;
           }
   //        else
   //        {
   //          cout << line1 << endl;
   //          cout << line2 << endl;
   //        }
         }
       }
       fin.close(); //close input file

       response == n;

     }
     else if (response == 'n')
       cout << "\n" << endl;
     else
       cout << "invalid entry" << endl;

     cout << "\n" << endl;


   }
   ```